# How to serve static gzip compressed file in Angular application?

Tags: angular, gzip, brotli

I Compressed my main.js to main.js.gzip. now how i can serve the gzip file in my browser

Comment: You don't need to compress your files yourself, there should be a setting in your webserver to do that.

Comment: Using Webpack i compressed my main.js, but how i can serve same to the web browser

Comment: You do not need to compress your files, the webserver that serves your files to the user's browser will have a setting to compress them.

Comment: Or you can precompress and have your webserver serve them and save some CPU. How exactly you do that depends on your webserver (Apache, Nginx, IIS, other).